# How can I use a mac to scroll and copy-paste text on the tmux via ssh?

Tags: ssh, terminal, osx, tmux, tmux-plugin-manager

I always use macos Terminal.app to control my ubuntu servers via ssh, and I need to use tmux to keep my program running in background.

Now, I know how to configure the tmux (on my ubuntu servers) to enable scroll screen by mouse:

add configuration to the .tmux.conf file :

```
set -g mouse on
```

But I found it doesn't work when I want to copy text on my Terminal.app, shift + left drag and shift + wheel can't copy and paste.

How should I configure tmux on server to enable scroll and copy-paste at same time ?

Or what kind of third-party terminal application should I use to realize these two functions?

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to look for the answer to this as well. I've switched from iTerm back to the default terminal app, but I'm having this issue on terminal.

For what it's worth, when I used iTerm with tmux, this wasn't an issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is my current `.tmux.conf` file and it allows to copy the selected text and paste it with the mouse wheel (linux style). My

```
set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"

set -g mouse on

# enable cut and paste
bind C-c run "tmux save-buffer - | xclip -i -sel clipboard"
bind C-v run "tmux set-buffer \"$(xclip -o -sel clipboard)\"; tmux past-buffer"
```

System Version: macOS 13.2 (22D49)

Kernel Version: Darwin 22.3.0